# Working with Unicode in R

Tags: r, unicode-string

I read in text from a MySQL table into and R dataframe. (using RODBC, sqlFetch). Have two questions:

1. How do I figure out if R has read it in as utf-8? It's character
   type but what's the function to show encoding?
2. How do I compute the number of characters in an Unicode string in R?

The `length` function does not work with Unicode and always returns 1 I think.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark if your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to read the encoding (assuming it is specified) with:

```
Encoding(x)
```

The number of characters can be determined with:

```
nchar(x)
```